# Non increasing sequence on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}^\ast}$, non increasing. Denote $x_0 = \lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n$, and $C= \{x_n |n\geq 0\}$.
Question:

$\forall r>0 \ \exists p\in \mathbb{N} \ \exists \{y_1,\dots,y_p\}\subset C \ \forall y\in C \ \exists j\in \{1,\dots,p\}$ $(\vert y- y_{j}\vert \leq r \text{ and } \forall k\in \{1,\dots,p\}\setminus \{j\} \vert y - y_k \vert> r)$

[**Translation:** $C$ is the set of all points in the sequence, together with the limit point.  For all $r>0$ there is some finite subset $X\subset C$ such that

i) every point $c\in C$ lies within a distance $r$ from some element $x$ of $X$ - $|x-c|\le r$.

ii) this $x$ is unique - if $y\in X$ and $y\ne x$, then $|y-c|>r$.]

Proof or counterexemple?

Thanks!

Comment: How do we know that the limit of the sequence exists?

Comment: The limit, exists because $x_n$ is non increasing and bounded. I tried on examples, the set $X$ is not trivial to find so I doubt the proof is by construction.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do, is in some sense dividing your unit interval (or more precisely the set corresponding to your sequence) into finitely many disjoint intervals of same length with middle points in your sequence. Even without fixed middlepoints this seems wrong (the problem here is disjoint!):

As possible counterexamples you can consider the points $\{0;1;1.5;2;3\}$ and $r=1$ (divided by 10):

**Spoileralert! Don't Read further if you want to do it on your own (you should at least try)**

---

---

---

If $0 \in X$ then because of the uniqueness neither $1,1.5$ nor $2$ is in $X$ since all of them have distance $\leq 1$ to $1$ (condition (ii) ). But this leaves only $3$ as possible element in $X$ and hence condition (i) is not fullfilled for $1.5$. If $1 \in X$, then samewise we have a problem with $3$. But when neither $0$ nor $1 \in X$ holds, we have a problem with condition (i) and $0$.